# How to find the next lower integer (with the same number of 1s)

Tags: java, computer-science

How to find the next lower binary number for an integer (same number of 1s)? For example: if given input number n = 10 (1010), the function should return 9 (1001), or n = 14 (1110) then return 13 (1101), or n = 22 (10110) then return 21 (10101), n = 25 (11001) then return 22 (10110)... etc.

Comment: Do your own homework bro

Comment: This is not hw. Just fun stuff to see if anyone can come up with a short cool answer for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this.

```
static int nextLower(int n) {
   int bc = Integer.bitCount(n);
   for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
     if (Integer.bitCount(i) == bc)
        return i;
   throw new RuntimeException(n+" is the lowest with a bit count of "+bc);
}
```

Of course if this is homework you are going to have trouble convincing someone you wrote this ;)

Comment: This algo did NOT work. Try it with 25 and return the same number. Haven't you tried to run it?

Comment: @FredtonDoan Ok, a simple bug I am sure you could have fixed.  I suggest you demand a refund from StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't think it is that simple or making your code working though. For the big number, it require more bits to flip and that is where the actual problem arise. Thanks for trying though :-)

Comment: @FredtonDoan Ok, give me an example where it wouldn't work.  Why would flipping more bits matter?  This can flip all the bits as it tries every positive value if needed.

Comment: @FredtonDoan He also said that it worked just fine, but his might be faster.

Comment: @FredtonDoan This works fine for me and does literally what you asked. Decrements the number until the number of 1s is the same.

Comment: I don't think my code will actually be faster, unless you use million-order numbers. And this code has nothing to do with flipping, it's just brute-force search (and it works).

Comment: Agree but need a little twist in the func otherwise it returns the same number as the input and it is O(n). I also like Peter code because it looks really clean.

Comment: @FredtonDoan Peter edited its code 45 minutes ago. It works now.

Comment: Yes. I used Peter's first posted. The update worked well and VERY CLEAN! In term of big-O, Your is faster though.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of clarity, in this answer I will use the term 'cardinality' to indicate the number of 1s in the binary representation of a number.

One (obvious) way is to run a downwards loop, and seek for the first number with the same cardinality as your input (just like Peter Lawrey suggested).

I don't think this is inefficient, because I guess the output number is always pretty close to the input. More precisely, all you have to do is to find the rightmost '10' bit sequence, and change it to '01'. Then replace the right part with a number having all 1s at its left, as many as you can, without breaking the postcondition. This brings us to another solution, which consists in converting the number to a binary string (like user2573153 showed you), performing the replacement (with a regular expression, maybe), and then converting back to int.

A slightly faster version of Peter's algorithm should be the following, which performs on integers the manipulation I proposed you for strings:

```
static int nextLower(int n) {
    int fixPart = 0;
    int shiftCount = 0;

    while ((n & 3) != 2) {
        if (n == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    fixPart + " is the lowest number with its cardinality");
        }

        fixPart |= (n & 1) << shiftCount;
        shiftCount += 1;
        n /= 2;
    }

    int fixZeros = shiftCount - Integer.bitCount(fixPart);
    return ((n ^ 3) << shiftCount) | (((1 << shiftCount) - 1) & ~((1 << fixZeros) - 1));
}
```

which is O(log n) rather than O(n), but it's definitely harder to understand, and may also be practically slower, due to its complexity. Anyway, you could only notice a difference if you try with some huge difficult number.

#### EDIT

I tried a little benchmark, and found that this code is 67% faster than Peter Lawrey's *when applied consecutively to all numbers from 2 to 100,000,000*. I don't think this is enough to justify the increased code complexity.

Comment: This is basically what I was thinking. Find the rightmost 10 and flip it.

Answer (score 1):

I like such binary task, so to find next lower number you should find right most 1 followed by 0 and exchange them,. UPDATE: you need to "reorder" the rest part of number with 1s at left and 0s at right

```
10    1010 ->
 9    1001
14    1110 ->
13    1101
25   11001 ->
22   10110
```

here is sample code:

```
    int originalValue = 25;
    int maskToCheck = 2; // in binary 10b
    int clearingMask = 1;
    int settingMask = 0;
    int zeroCount = 0;
    while (maskToCheck > 0)
    {
        if ( (originalValue&(maskToCheck|(maskToCheck>>1))) == maskToCheck ) // we found such
        {
            int newValue = originalValue&(~maskToCheck); // set 1 with 0
            newValue = newValue&(~clearingMask)|(settingMask<<zeroCount); // clear all the rest bits, and set most valuable ones
            newValue = newValue|(maskToCheck>>1); // set 0 with 1
            System.out.println("for " + originalValue + " we found " + newValue);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( (originalValue&(maskToCheck>>1)) > 0) // we have 1 bit in cleared part
                settingMask = (settingMask<<1) | 1;
            else
                zeroCount++;
            maskToCheck = maskToCheck<<1; // try next left bits
            clearingMask = (clearingMask<<1)|1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You answered while I was still counting bits :) Excellent approach!

Comment: It seemed only work with 1 bit to flip. Did you try it with number 25 which requires 2 flip. The larger number will require more flips. That is the hard part. One flip is very simple.

Comment: @FredtonDoan `for 25 we found 21`, check the while loop

Comment: for 25, it should return 22 which is the NEXT lower :-)

Comment: Yeah, I found the same :( What if you keep bit #0 (as this one should always change) and only shift the *next* bit left-wise? (edit: nope.)